# Combination of RawPy and imageio result in red image

Tags: image-processing, python-imageio, raw, dng, rawpy

I want to do some image processing using .dng files. I am using rawpy to convert the file into a numpy array. Then imageio to save the image. It is a very simple code, given on the rawpy webpage.

The resulting .png image is not as I expect it to be. The result is very red, while the raw image isn't. It is like a red overlay on the original image.

The code I am using is:

```
import rawpy
import imageio

path = r'img\CGraw.dng'
with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess()
    
imageio.imsave(r"img\spyraw.png",rgb)
```

Original dng image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ip4U7KvI4-Lit4u7AuaHfoHIkXvGNRFk/view?usp=sharing

Resulting png image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CyrqJS2Osj3u-jEzLSxSy5eKMUP4csAV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3):

Simply add the argument `use_camera_wb=True`.

According to the [documentation](https://letmaik.github.io/rawpy/api/rawpy.Params.html):

> use_camera_wb (bool) – whether to use the as-shot white balance values

That means using the white balance coefficients that the camera found automatically during the shot (the values are stored as Exif data of the DNG file).

I don't know why the default is `use_camera_wb=False`. (It could be a result of poor job wrapping [LibRaw](https://www.libraw.org/) with Python).
In my opinion the default supposed to be `use_camera_wb=True` and `use_auto_wb=False`.

We may also select the output Color Space: `output_color=rawpy.ColorSpace.sRGB`.

The colors looks right, but there may be other pitfalls that I am not aware of... (I don't have enough experience with `rawpy` and `LibRaw`).

---

```python
import rawpy
import imageio

path = r'img\CGraw.dng'

with rawpy.imread(path) as raw:
    rgb = raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True, use_auto_wb=False, output_color=rawpy.ColorSpace.sRGB)
    
imageio.imsave(r"img\spyraw.png",rgb)
```

---

Output (downscaled):
[image]

Comment: Top sleuthing - well done!

Comment: Thanks', it actually took me an hour and a half of sleuthing work...

Comment: That did it! Results are much better now. Thanks!